# How can I specify apigateway's role to give permission to invoke a lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam

I am using AWS apigateway to trigger a lambda function. I deployed them from serverless framework, the configuration looks like:

```
handler:
  handler: src/index.handler
  name: handler
  tracing: true
  role: updateRole
  events:
    - http:
        path: /contact/{id}
        method: patch
        integration: lambda
        request:
          parameters:
              paths:
                id: true
```

after deploy, it works perfect. But what I don't understand is how I can find out where the iam role/policy defined for this API integration?

When open AWS console, it shows me the right configuration in the "Integration Request" tab:

But I can't find anywhere it specifies the IAM role to this integration. How can I find it or update it?

[image]

Comment: On your screenshot the next entry box is **Lambda Function** and the very next box is literally **Execution Role**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions to execute a function from API, are set using [resource-based policies for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/access-control-resource-based.html), not IAM role. In lambda console they are listed as:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. How do I know when I should use resource based policy or identity based policy? In my case, I thought it should be identity based policy

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao Sometimes docs say that, but sometimes its try and see thing.